# Showing that $ \Vert x\Vert_{Q} := \langle x,Qx\rangle^{1/2}$ defines a norm where $Q$ is symmetric, positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let matrix $Q \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ be symmetric and positive definite. I want to prove that $ \Vert x\Vert_{Q} := \langle x,Qx \rangle ^{1/2}$ defines a norm. So the first two properties are quite easy to show. I am more interested in

$$\Vert x + y\Vert_{Q} \le \Vert x\Vert_{Q} + \Vert y\Vert_{Q}$$

I know how it works with Cauchy-Schwarz, but for obvious reasons I can not use that $\langle x,Qx\rangle$ defines are scalar product (otherwise there is nothing to show at all!).

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than $<, >$ does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that there exists $S$ symmetric positive definite such that $S^2=Q$.

You get $\|x\|_Q=\|Sx\|$ and from this the thesis follows

Answer (score 0):

You can show that $\langle v,Qw\rangle$ is an inner product, and then invoke Cauchy-Schwarz.